Which file in the open source project contains calculating L2 and Cosine score function?
According to the official website description, the score function can be l2 or cosine.
However, the results I calculated based on the formula on the official website are different from the results obtained through open source. So, I would like to ask where the file for calculating the score function is in the open source?

"Off-site resource requests" are categorically off-topic here. Instead of asking someone to locate source code for you, why not ask about the results differing from what you expect, showing a [mre] that lets someone else validate that difference in behavior? (A tiny 3-dimensional vector and just a few points should be enough -- the goal is to provide the shortest, simplest case that lets others validate the problem and check their answers).
